# Is there a way to deploy DaemonSet only on nodes with active deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, cadvisor

I'm deploying my service under my namespace. We have a worker node farm and my service will only utilize a small subset of its nodes.

I want to deploy a DaemontSet of cAdvisors but I only want them to run in the nodes not related to my namespace. If possible, how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DaemonSet runs one pod per node. You cant bypass a node.

Answer (score 2):

`ScheduleDaemonSetPods` is a kubernetes feature that allows you to schedule DaemonSets using the default scheduler instead of the DaemonSet controller, by adding the `NodeAffinity` term to the DaemonSet pods, instead of the `.spec.nodeName` term. [Kubernetes Document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#scheduled-by-default-scheduler)

For example below k8s manifest will create Pods on nodes with `type=target-host-name`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: testdaemon
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testdaemon
    annotations:
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: type
                operator: In
                values:
                - target-host-name
      containers:
      - name: testdaemon
        image: nginx
```